# How to run flush_rewrite_rules on activation after i register my custom post type using Wordpress Boilerplate Plugin

Tags: plugins, activation

I have created a plugin that register a new CPT but it doesnt work because i have to `flush_rewrite_rules()`
(i can do this by going into the permalink setting page and save, but its not the right way)

I have read inside the wordpress codex that i have to `flush_rewrite_rules()` on activation, but its not working cuz `flush_rewrite_rules()` runs before i register the CPT, to work it must run after...

I am using this https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate

And it has a class that runs on activation of the plugin i have added there this `flush_rewrite_rules()`

**Edit**

The boilerplate i have used is already structured with activation/deactivation classes, for example

```
function activate_l_erbario() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-l-erbario-activator.php';
    L_Erbario_Activator::activate();

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_l_erbario' );
```

and inside class-l-erbario-activator.php i have

```
class L_Erbario_Activator {
    public static function activate() {

    }

}
```

**GITHUB WITH THE PLUGIN**

https://github.com/NeaMitika/CPT-Erbario-Wordpress

/admin/class-l-erbario-admin.php -> here i register the CPT

/includes/class-l-erbario.php -> and here i add the add_action with the CPT

Comment: So if you need it to run after the post type is registered and when the plugin is activated, you'll probably want use the activation function to hook `flush_rewrite_rules()` onto something such as `admin_init`, rather than call it directly

Comment: On the Wordpress Codex it says this:
// ATTENTION: This is *only* done during plugin activation hook in this example!
    // You should *NEVER EVER* do this on every page load!!
    flush_rewrite_rules();

Comment: OK, then how is that getting run before your CPT registration? Which hook are you using to register your CPT?

Comment: I have edited the main question on how the plugin handles activation

Comment: Thanks. How does it handle the registration? But I'd guess the simplest thing to do is to do the registration again in the activation hook, before calling flush_rewrite_rules.

Comment: i made a GitHub repo with the plugin so you can watch everything 
https://github.com/NeaMitika/CPT-Erbario-Wordpress

Comment: Is it corrrect to run Register CPT on plugin activation and then after again on each 'init' as required by wordpress?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I don't think the plugin's init hook is called when it is loaded for activation.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days trying and trying and trying... i asked a youtuber who develops using the same Wordpress Plugin Boilerplate and he pointed me to this article:

https://andrezrv.com/2014/08/12/efficiently-flush-rewrite-rules-plugin-activation/

It adds an option inside_option table and it will flush  rewrite rules based on that :)
It worked perfectly